# How to create a reusable component library for Next.js with TypeScript and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have been using Next.js recently and have been creating components like buttons, inputs, and cards using Tailwind CSS for each project. However, rewriting these components for every new project is quite tedious and redundant. While I have explored libraries like Ant Design, their styles don't quite match my preferences.

I want to create my own reusable component library similar to Ant Design but with my own styling, using TypeScript and Tailwind CSS. I have searched online, but most resources primarily cover creating libraries for React. Are there any specific considerations or best practices for building a component library specifically for Next.js with TypeScript and Tailwind CSS?

I would appreciate any guidance, tutorials, or resources on setting up the project structure, organizing components, handling styles with Tailwind CSS, and publishing the library for easy consumption in Next.js projects. Any advice or experiences shared would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Building a component library from scratch will be a lot of work, you will need to handle all accessibility-related and internationalization-related things by yourself. On the other hand, if you are looking for custom-styled components without any default styles try starting with any unstyled component libraries.  You can start building your own library from these. Some of the popular ones are [React  Aria](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/), [Arc UI](https://ark-ui.com/), [Headless UI](https://headlessui.com/) ...etc

For styling you can use any styling libraries of your choice. Once all components are styled and ready to be shipped, you can use bundlers like Tsup or Rollup to make an npm package of your library.